# Generate Haddock for hidden members

Tags: haskell, haddock

Can I generate Haddock documentation for hidden members. My use case is that I have a type `T` that is shown in the signature of some functions. As in e.g. `f :: T -> U`, `g :: T -> U`. I'd like users of my library to know what `T` is used for, but not actually export it. Does it make sense? Is this possible?

Comment: Both `stack haddock` and `cabal new-haddock` have a `--haddock-internal` flag that you could try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add

```
{-# OPTIONS_HADDOCK ignore-exports #-}
```

which will generate Haddock documentation as if there were an empty export list -- i.e., as if everything were exported in the module.

Alternatively, the C preprocessor can be used to hide/show some entries in the Haddock docs. One probably has to invoke haddock with something like this (untested)

```
haddock --optghc=-cpp --optghc=-DHADDOCK ...
```

and then, in the haskell source,

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
module M
    ( export1
    , export2
#ifdef HADDOCK
    , notExportedButWeWantDocsAnyway
#endif
    , export3
    ) where
...
```

(I thought that haddock already defined a macro to witness its presence, but I can't find that in its docs. One can always use a user-defined haddock flag. Or maybe it was [this one](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1237).)

Comment: Thanks for the input. The problem with the module header is if the module (as in my case) is a hidden module as well. Good to know that ignore-exports can be used like this.

Comment: @fredefox I have no idea about how one could handle that :-/